# Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token < in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am getting "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <"
in the following code. Please point out the error. 
Is it related to jQuery because when I remove the code
below the 'load 3d' comment it works without any errors.

Please Help.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/static/jstree/_lib/jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/static/jstree/jquery.jstree.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">

$(function () {

// load the 3D Script
$("#container").ready(function(){
    $.getScript("json_model.js");
});

// load the jstree  
$("#demo").jstree({ 
    "json_data" : {
        "ajax": {
            "url": "/static/templates/json_tree.js",
            "data":function(n){
            }
        }
    },
    "plugins" : ["themes", "json_data"]

    }).bind("select_node.jstree", function (e, data){});
});
</script>
```

```
<div id="demo">
</div>

<div id="container">
</div>
```

Comment: My guess would be it's something in your `json_model.js` file, since when you comment out the loading of that, it works fine. Can you post the contents of `json_model.js`?

Comment: In whitch line is the error? Do you have `<script>` tags in `json_model.js`? Remove them.

Comment: Just a guess: you/your script is probably trying to load a file which it expects to contain JSON. Instead it is getting HTML (404 error may be).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What do you get when you hit `/static/templates/json_tree.js` by itself? Do you see JSON or Javascript? If you have Firebug, take a look at the Net tab to see what response you receive from the URL.

If it's seeing `<`, it's probably because the function expects Javascript or JSON, but is seeing HTML.

Answer (score 1):

you must check your path to js file or change the dir name where file js in, sometime server don't get path. For example if you have public and js dir out of public and you also have the same inside public, but the path the same http://www.somthing.com/js/jsfile.js and server don't know what file must be get.

Comment: I'm using /index.php as a router, and my path needed a "../" prefixed since the URI was in a virtual sub-directory. Thanks for the clue!